# Hibernate : Fetch collection

Tags: hibernate

I encontered a problem while trying to get a collection of elements :  the set of Friend is empty.

There is 3 classes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {
@Id
@Column(name="USER_ID", nullable=false) 
private String mail;

@Column(name="PASSWORD")
private String password;

@Column(name="SURNAME")
private String surname;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String name = null;

@Column(name="STATUT")
private StatutUser statut;

@Column(name="PHONENUMBER")
private int phoneNumber;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy="friendPK.friend")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<Friend> friends = new HashSet<Friend>();

    ... 
    Some getters and setters
```

The second one :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FRIEND")
public class Friend
{

@EmbeddedId 
public FriendPK friendPK;

@Column(name = "FRIEND_STATUT")
private StatutFriend statutFriend;

... 
}
```

The last one :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable 
public class FriendPK implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER1_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID")
    protected User user1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER2_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID")
    protected User friend;
}
```

When I try to get all friends' user, the collection is empty.

Here's the file where the method to add a relationship is :

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private EntityManager manager;

public String addFriends(String mail1, String mail2){

        EntityTransaction t;
        t = manager.getTransaction();

        try{
            t.begin();

            User user = manager.find(User.class, mail1);

            User friend =  manager.find(User.class, mail2);

            Friend f = new Friend();
            f.setStatutFriend(StatutFriend.TOCHECK);
            FriendPK friendPK = new FriendPK();
            friendPK.setFriend(friend);
            friendPK.setUser1(user);
            f.setFriendPK(friendPK);

            Set<Friend> relationship = new HashSet<Friend>();
            relationship =  user.getFriends();
            relationship.add(f);

            Set<Friend> relationship2 = new HashSet<Friend>();
            relationship2 = friend.getFriends();
            relationship2.add(f);

            user.setFriends(relationship);
            friend.setFriends(relationship2);

            manager.persist(user);

            t.commit();
            error.setReq(StatutReq.DONE);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            error.setReq(StatutReq.ABORTED);
            error.setError(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (t.isActive())
            {
                t.rollback();
            }
        }
```

Please be indulgent with my code... I'm a beginner !
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight, the code seems correct despite your architecture looks strange.
What does the class friendFK stand for ?
Doesn't a user just need to hold a set of users Set ?
From a database point of view, a relational table is necessary but not in your java model.

If i were you, i would delete this class and use the hbm2dll tool to generate a correct matching database schema.

Could you specify your Hibernate and jars versions and give us your hibernate config file to check it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed my global structure without using the friendFK. And now it's working !